# Why do a Fixed div containing a table hides under google chart while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, scroll

```
<div id="google chart">
    </div>

    <div>
        some more div
    </div>

    <div>
    <img>
         <div>
             <table>
         </div>
</div>
```

1.Table is displayed only on hovering on img/div (which is fixed top from clientx.)

My question is when I scroll up my table hides under google chart ( chart created by google chart api)

Comment: can u show us the google api chart ?

Comment: Have you tried to use something like `z-index: 100;` on the table?

Comment: z-indez :100 works fine.